# Mac app makes the computer unexpectedly reboot

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, nstableview, xamarin.mac

I've encountered a pretty weird *bug* in my macOS app.

When I do specific things in my macOS app, my computer just restarts unexpectedly without any warnings or errors. Any other applications work just fine and the same behaviour is not experiencing while using them. Has anyone of you ever faced something similar? Is this a new macOS issue?

My environment:

- macbook pro retina mid 1012, High Sierra 10.13.4 Beta
- **Xamarin.Mac** application, building in Visual Studio For Mac
- Use xib files for UI, Autolayout is **unchecked**
- Minimum system version for the app is **10.9**
- One window app, use NSTableView inside NSViewController

The issue seems to relate to file system operations and probably NSTableView row selection. Computer reboots when I click a row in table view; or push new view controller; or read some file.
It is not a 100% reproducible thing, what makes the investigation really annoying.

Also, the app worked fine on older macOS versions. I've faced it recently after some system updates.

Comment: Try it on a macOS non-beta release (personally I have a had bad experiences with the last two beta releases, ie. 17E150g. Some of the Apple forum threads are pointing fingers at meltdown & spectre patches, others at the newest (e)GPU features as graphic memory corruption is really bad)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SushiHangover. The thing is the app seems fine on non-beta Sierra, and even on High Sierra 10.13.2 if I remember correctly... I started experiencing this on the macOS latest updates. But it is in my app only, what makes me wonder what exactly I'm doing wrong. Maybe extreme memory use, or file-system changing/reading during some UI calculations, or a wrong tableview use, no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking Console -> System Reports for crash logs in WindowServer or other System components. I've seen a number of crashes in 10.13.